# Visual Studio Post Build Event if exists

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

I want to call a batch file in my post build step in Visual Studio. Locally the batch file exists, just the command

```
call "$(SolutionDir)PostBuildSen.bat" "$(TargetDir)" "$(TargetName)"
```

correctly calls and executes the batch file.

However when I want to check if the batch file exists first (since others will use the same Post Build Event), I get the error

> :VCEnd" exited with code 255.

The command is

```
if exists "$(SolutionDir)PostBuildSen.bat" call "$(SolutionDir)PostBuildSen.bat" "$(TargetDir)" "$(TargetName)"
```

The Diagnostic output tells me

> 2>  Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.

How do you handle this?

The Solution Directory contains a folder with an underscore, i.e. `\Dev_Main\` and I have read that for the batch file that is to be called at least that doesn't work. However I am not sure if that is the issue with folders as well and how to cope with it. Also, since the `call` command works, I am not sure this is the problem.

Furthermore, if I replace the `call` with `cmd /C`, the exit code is 1 and the (minmal) output tells me

> 1>The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Also, I will add this as a custom command to a CMakeLists file later on, so the solution needs to work with that.

Comment: There should be a diagnostic visible in the Output window, produced by the command processor when it keels over.  Should look like "c:\foo\bar\PostBuildSen.bat was unexpected at this time".  You got the syntax subtly wrong, it is `if exist` instead of `if exists`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the issue indeed. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Meh, it is just a typo.  I don't understand why you did not see the diagnostic so hard to post an authoritative answer.  Feel free to use what you've learned to complete the Q+A.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the diagnostic output that really let me see that it's just a syntax error. I may of course have missed something, but the only thing I really read was "this does not work". I will close it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant's comment, I solved the problem. The query for the file needs to be `if exist` rather than `if exists`.

Comment: Worth pointing out that you can do the opposite as well: `IF NOT EXIST...`